# help with soql to fetch sharing details of partner account

Tags: apex, soql, sharing, partner-communities, roles

I have partner community users which have access to our partner community. We have couple of sharing settings applied for partner account when the record is created in Salesforce. We can find this onclick of sharing button from Partner Account page.

Is there anyway I can get a list of those sharing details which are applied for the partner account. Please help me with the SOQL or any other workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Each SObject has a sharing object (for example Account has AccountShare). You can fetch these with the condition ParentID = :accId.

Further details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

Comment: You are super awesome Christian. I got the query but here, I can  only able to fetch names of Public Groups and Users type with UserOrGroup.name. I cannot able to fetch names of roles type which are assigned for an account. Could you please help me with that.

Comment: for roles do you mean UserRole?

Comment: I mean Portal Roles that is assigned for Partner Account. In the query, I could only see names for Users and Public Groups but not shared roles like Portal Role. Please suggest